# code is running twice

Tags: vb.net

I have already got the start date to verify if after end date and display message, but when i put the following code .focus it seems to run the code twice
i have tried everything 
the handle is leave
tried that it didnt work
i also put it into a new thread, didnt work
and also into a function, didnt work
im at my ends wit on this one

here is the code

```
Function DateCompare(ByVal Start As Date, ByVal Finish As Date, ByVal WhichDate As String)
  If WhichDate = "DateIn" Then
    If DateTime.Compare(Start, Finish) > 0 Then
      MsgBox("Dates Are Invalid : Date In Cannot be after Date Out, Please Amend", vbExclamation, "Dates Are Incorrect")
      Return False
      Exit Function
    Else
      Return True
    End If
  Else
    If DateTime.Compare(Finish, Start) < 0 Then
      MsgBox("Dates Are Invalid : Date Out Cannot be before Date In, Please Amend", vbExclamation, "Dates Are Incorrect")
      Return False
      Exit Function
    Else
      Return True
    End If
  End If
End Function

Private Sub dtpDateTimeIn_leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles dtpDateTimeIn.Leave
  Dim result As Boolean
  result = DateCompare(dtpDateTimeIn.Value, dtpDateTimeOut.Value, "DateIn")
  If result = False Then
    dtpDateTimeIn.Focus()
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub dtpDateTimeOut_leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles dtpDateTimeOut.Leave
  Dim result As Boolean
  result = DateCompare(dtpDateTimeIn.Value, dtpDateTimeOut.Value, "DateOut")
  If result = False Then
    dtpDateTimeOut.Focus()
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Validating` events instead.  They were made for this:

```
Private Sub dtpDateTimeIn_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CancelEventArgs) Handles dtpDateTimeIn.Validating
  e.Cancel = Not DateCompare(dtpDateTimeIn.Value, dtpDateTimeOut.Value, "DateIne")
End Sub

Private Sub dtpDateTimeOut_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CancelEventArgs) Handles dtpDateTimeOut.Validating
  e.Cancel = Not DateCompare(dtpDateTimeIn.Value, dtpDateTimeOut.Value, "DateOut")
End Sub
```